# Можно ли получить URL-ы открытых ссылок через js

Tags: javascript

Как в js получить список открытых вкладок в браузере?
Допустим у нас открыты ютуб, википедия, вк, и localhost

И на локалхосте я хочу вывести в консоль url-ы всех открытых вкладок браузера

Comment: Если это не расширения для бразуера - сделать это невозможно. Хотя даже с раширением мне кажется это нельзя

Comment: если это действие будет вызываться в браузере, то нельзя.